# xna 4.0 and loading images fails

Tags: c#, xna-4.0

I'm trying to load png images into my game, but for some reason it can't find the images.

This is my Title screen that is trying to load the images:

```
public TitleScreen(ContentManager contentManager)
  {
     titleScreen = contentManager.Load<Texture2D>("gfx\\titleScreen");
     bgScreen = contentManager.Load<Texture2D>("gfx\\bgScreen");
     arialFont = contentManager.Load<SpriteFont>("Arial");
  }
```

Here I'm setting the root directory for the content:

```
Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
```

When my program hits titlescreen, it fails to find the image, however the path to it is correct and the images are also set to be Content and copied to output directory.

When I try to debug it, it tells me it can't find image "Content\gfx\titleScreen.xnb". For some reason it is trying to load an xnb file, is there anywhere that I can change it, or do I need to do anything else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In XNA Images are compiled .xnb files and not .png or .jpg

**XNA 3.0 || XNA 3.1**
You add your Content to the Content folder within your project

**XNA 4.0**
You have a Content Project and you add a Content Reference in your current project

Also Make sure you set the properties of the images:
Right Click on Content Item -> Properties -> Set the following

- Build Action: Compile
- Content Importer/Processor: Texture - XNA Framework (Textures)
- Content Importer/Processor: Sprite Font Description - XNA Framework (Fonts)
- Do not copy

Comment: Thanks, seems my example that I was following is 3.x and I'm working with the 4.0 version, had not thought there where that much changes like this.

Comment: doh! I had the same problem... forgot to RE-build instead of just build. :P

Answer (score 5):

Additionally remember to rebuild solution after adding new resource to content project.

Comment: This is what the issue was for me. References must have gotten messed up in my screwy version control.

Answer (score 2):

In XNA you typically load processed files (`xnb` files). You'd add a content project to your solution, and reference that in your main game project (usually this is set up when you create a new game).

You add your files (assets) in there. When your game is built the content project is built, which processes your assets, producing `xnb` files, which is what the `ContentManager.Load` method wants.